# Can a docker instance cause harm to the host?

Tags: docker

Is the docker host completely protected for anything the docker instance can do?

As long as you don't expose a volume to the docker instance, are there other ways it can actually connect into the host and 'hack' it?

For example, say I allow customers to run code inside of a server that I run.  I want to understand the potential security implications of allowing a customer to run arbitrary code inside of an docker instance.

Comment: Are you planning on letting your customers start their own containers (i.e., will they have access to the docker api)?

Comment: @larsks No, I will basically run a command that will pull their git repository and build their project inside of a container that I control.  so their project could have any custom code in it.

Answer (score 1):

All processes inside Docker are isolated from the host machine. The cannot by default see or interfere with other processes. This is guranteed by the process namespaces used by docker.

As long as you don't mount crucial stuff (example: `docker.sock`) onto the container, there are no security risks associated with running a container, and even with allowing code execution inside the container.

For a list of security features in docker, check [Docker security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/).

Comment: Say I mount a volume to a specific folder, could the container traverse the volume and access parent folders?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is shared between the host and the docker container. This is less separation than lets say a VM has.

Runing any untrusted container is NOT SECURE. There are kernel vulnerabilities, which can be abused and ways to break out of containers.

Thats why its a best practice for example to either not use root user in containers or have a separate user namespace for containers.

Comment: how do I set the user namespace inside the container?